# Use group by in select from nested queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run a query similar to the following

```
SELECT t.ticketid, 
       Min(oo.incidentid). max(t.createddate) 
FROM   (SELECT ticketid, 
               NAME, 
               createddate 
        FROM   ticket) t 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT incidentid, 
                          created, 
                          date, 
                          NAME 
                   FROM   oops) oo 
               ON t.ticketid = oo.incidentid
```

Now, when I run this query it tells me that for example, ticket id needs to be contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. However, when I add it at the and of the query, I still get

> ticketid column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What anyone tells me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Min(oo.incidentid). max(t.createddate)` did you want to write this: `Min(oo.incidentid), max(t.createddate)` ?

Comment: You're tying to use min & max *and* pull the id, by pulling the id you are saying you want each individual row, by using min/max you are saying you want aggregated rows. You can't have both :)

Comment: @nina_dev have you found any help in the answers provided below ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can test this code :

```
SELECT t.ticketid, 
       Min(oo.incidentid) min_c,
       max(t.createddate) max_c
FROM   (SELECT ticketid, 
               NAME, 
               createddate 
        FROM   ticket) t 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT incidentid, 
                          created, 
                          date, 
                          NAME 
                   FROM   oops) oo 
               ON t.ticketid = oo.incidentid 
               group by t.ticketid
```

is OK. Check it please. Thanks!
Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c2a31ff286a041e4ddb9da2522422c55)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have so many subqueries?

```
SELECT t.ticketid, 
       MIN(oo.incidentid), MAX(t.createddate) 
FROM ticket) JOIN
     oop oo 
     ON t.ticketid = oo.incidentid 
GROUP BY t.ticketid;
```

And, that said, you don't even need a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT oo.incidentid, 
       MIN(oo.incidentid), MAX(t.createddate) 
FROM oop oo 
GROUP BY oo.incidentid;
```